# SQLite can't select

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following SQL returns an error:

```
select * from(1, select random())
```

However if you change the order of it, the error goes away.

```
select * from(select random(), 1)
```

Why is this so?

Similarly, what I wanted to do was get two random numbers, which didn't work

```
select * from(select random(), select random());
```

But it works if you enclose it in brackets

```
select * from((select random()),(select random()));
```

So the question here is: Is there something wrong with...

1. My SQL statement?
2. SQLite?
3. the SQL standard?

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The first part is obvious - select * from(1, select random())     doesn't work because 1,select random() is invalid.  select 1, random() is valid.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Lite are distinct products.  Which are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SELECT statement always starts with the word SELECT (or WITH, but not in some databases, nor in a subquery), so your first query:

```
select * from(1, select random())
```

is invalid because as you can see the subquery starts with the number 1, not the word SELECT

Your second query:

```
select * from(select random(), 1)
```

is valid because in the subquery the query starts with the word SELECT

This query:

```
select * from(select random(), select random());
```

is invalid because in the from clause you have to list tables, views, or inline views (what you're attempting to do). An inline view has to be a full query meeting the minimum requirements of a select statement, and that query has to be enclosed (). In your query above you are separating two queries with a comma. That is not how you separate queries, otherwise how would the database differentiate between multiple items in your select list and the start of a new query?

This version:

```
select * from((select random()),(select random()));
```

Is correct because you've enclosed each inline view in () and separated each enclosed inline view with a comma. Before you did not enclose them.

Comment: Thanks for being the only answer to address the full question and not echo my comment posted 15 minutes before.  +1

Comment: SQLite [supports WITH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (since version 3.8.3).

Answer (score -1):

The parameters in a `FROM` or `JOIN` clause must be either table names or subqueries, the latter must be enclosed in parentheses. When you write:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT RANDOM(), 1)
```

`SELECT RANDOM(), 1` is a valid subquery. But when you write:

```
SELECT * FROM (1, SELECT RANDOM())
```

`1, SELECT RANDOM()` is not a subquery. A subquery must start with `SELECT`.